# How to store settings for a JavaScript/jQuery page being tracked by git?

Tags: javascript, jquery, git

As a server developer, I would get my PHP code to access environment variables for deployment settings.

How would you approach the same problem for a purely HTML/JavaScript/jQuery page?

For example, would you load in a JSON file?

I'm tracking the page in git, and I don't want to save person-specific information in the main repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some build system (ant, phing, shell-scripts...) and create the template for config file.

On the build step just fill the template with real values (taken from environment or wherever you want) and prepend the real script with the configuration object.

As a result of building process you'll have the specific file for particular client.